# Add registers of sub-module to the regmap() of a module that new/instantiate it

Tags: chisel

I am trying to add the registers of of a sub module to the module where it is being instantiated. My usecase is a periphery in the rocket-chip with a few hw engines in it, for example crypto periphery with sha1 engine.
I've Implemented the sha1 as a sub-module with its own set of control registers

```
class sha1 extends Module {
    ....
    def sha1RegMap(offset: Int): Seq[(Int, Seq[RegField])] = {
        val regs = Seq(
            (offset)     -> Seq(Regfield(32,reg1,RegFileDesc("r1",""))),
            (offset + 4) -> Seq(Regfield(32,reg2,RegFileDesc("r2",""))),
            (offset + 8) -> Seq(Regfield(32,reg3,RegFileDesc("r3",""))), 
        )
        regs         
    } 
    ....
}
```

Then I tried to add it to the containing periphery module:

```
lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
    ...
    val sha1_engine = Module(new sha1)
    ...
    regmap(
        0x0 -> Seq(Regfield(32,creg1,RegFileDesc("cr1",""))),
        0x4 -> Seq(Regfield(32,creg2,RegFileDesc("cr2",""))),
        0x8 -> Seq(Regfield(32,creg3,RegFileDesc("cr3",""))),
        ++ sha1_engine.sha1RegMap(0xC):_*
 )
}
```

That didn't compile. How can I add the registers of the sub-module ?
Also what about when I need to add more sub-modules after the first one or even some local registers of the periphery itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following. I think you need the add the two `Seq`s together first then
convert them into a an argument list with the :_* operator. I might have more parens than necessary.

```
   lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
        ...
        val sha1_engine = Module(new sha1)
        ...
        regmap(
          (
            Seq(
                0x0 -> Seq(Regfield(32,creg1,RegFileDesc("cr1",""))),
                0x4 -> Seq(Regfield(32,creg2,RegFileDesc("cr2",""))),
                0x8 -> Seq(Regfield(32,creg3,RegFileDesc("cr3","")))
            )
            ++ sha1_engine.sha1RegMap(0xC)
          ):_*
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chick Markley ,  following your suggestion I now able to compile & elaborate. I fail on the firrtl pass with errors on undeclared references. example "Reference reg1 is not declared" ,reg1 is in the submodule.

Comment: I am asking around about this. It might have something to do with the properties of regmap but I am not sure and don't want to give a wrong answer. I should have an answer soon

Comment: I'm not making any progress on your follow-up question. I'd suggest you resubmit the updated code with the tag rocket-chip or if you can post the generated firrtl (perhaps in a gist) so I could take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Chick Markley for your willing to help with the follow-up question,I really appreciate that. I was able to find an example for that in the PWM module in the  sifive-block repository (https://github.com/sifive/sifive-blocks). apparently in order to reference the sub-module regs you need to hook them with io into the super class/module.